# Appending Custom Cell Label and TextField text to Array of Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a custom tableView cell with a UILabel and a UITextField. I would like to append the data from the textField with label to an array of dictionaries ([label:textfield]). I can get the textField data using textFieldDidEndEditing but I am not sure how to get the cell label for that same textfield. I would think I would need access to that cell's indexPath. I tried sending a notification to DidSelectRow but that seemed too complicated.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: expenseCell, for: indexPath) as! LineItemTableViewCell
        let sectionsArray = expenses[sections[indexPath.section]]
        let expenseItem = sectionsArray?[indexPath.row]
        cell.budgetLineItemView.label.text = expenseItem!
        cell.budgetLineItemView.lineItemTextField.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: UITextField Delegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //get textfield text after editing here
    }
```

This is my dictionary:

```
 var expenses:[String:[[String:Double]]] = ["Housing":[["Rent/Mortgage":0.0],
["Gas":0.0],["Water/Power":0.0],["Cable/Internet":0.0],["Garbage":0.0],["Property 
Tax":0.0],["Homeowners/Renters Insurance":0.0]],"Transportation":[["Car 
Payment":0.0],["Car Insurance":0.0],["Roadside Insurance":0.0]],"Other Expenses":
[["Health Insurance":0.0],["Life Insurance":0.0],["Disability Insurance":0.0],
["Student Loans":0.0],["Cell Phone":0.0],["Other":0.0]]]
```

Comment: You can do this `for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as! [UITableViewCell] {
            //do something with the cell here.}`

Comment: That allows me to see what each element at each visible cell is but it doesn't let me update and append the values of those cells to my dictionary (see update)

Comment: Doesn't let you update? what is the type of object do you have, if its a `NSArray or, NSDictionary` you need to use `NSMutableArray or, NSMutableDictionary` and after changing the values reload the table.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

why not setting up `tag` to each label and textFiled like follow in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
textField.tag = indexPath.row
```

and in the delegate `textFieldDidBeganEditing` or where necessary use the tag to get `cell` and then the `label` as below

```
let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: textField.tag, inSection: 0)
let currentCell = tblTest.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! youCellClass
```

then using `currentCell` you may access it's `label`

Comment: This is good but I'm not really wanting to mess with tags for this project. The visiblecells direction that was presented in the comments seems to be a good direction but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: second option could be to subclass your UILabel and textfield